# how could I lose weight and at the same time and try not to have skin excess or loose skin?

Tags: skin

I'am afraid that if I lose weight I will get loose skin, is there any way to avoid loose skin while losing weight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you lose weight at a healthy pace, i.e. two pounds or less a week, you should not have much excess skin. And, even if you do, loose skin will tighten up after a few months. Exercise helps, too.

Comment: Any references by any chance? I am wondering where the two pounds per weeks comes to action?